# Fitting the statistical distribution cdf function

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, statistics, curve-fitting

can anyone explain me why the **random points generated for the specific statistical distribution doesn't fit that distribution well**. And why the distribution parameters that are obtained by **cfd fitting of the random points look much better**?

I'm experiencing the same thing also by using the scipy.stats..fit on the any data. It looks worse than cdf fitting...

I must be doing somewhere really bad assumption...

Here is an example:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import stats
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

# fit by cdf 
#########################################################
def fit_lognorm_cfd(x_data, p_data):

    def lndist(x, sigma, loc, scale):
        return stats.lognorm.cdf(x, sigma, loc, scale)

    opt, pcov = curve_fit(lndist, x_data, p_data)

    return stats.lognorm(*opt)


# create some random points
#########################################################
# define some parameters
shape = 0.8   # sigma
loc = 0
mue = -0.5
scale = np.exp(mue)

# orig distribution
lndist = stats.lognorm(shape, loc=loc, scale=scale)

# get some random points
vals = stats.lognorm.rvs(shape, size=100)
vals = np.sort(vals)
pvals = np.cumsum(np.full(vals.size, 1/vals.size))

# fit by cfd function
lndist2=fit_lognorm_cfd(vals, pvals)

x = np.linspace(lndist.ppf(0.001),
                lndist.ppf(0.999), 100)
xlg = np.logspace(np.log10(lndist.ppf(0.001)),
                  np.log10(lndist.ppf(0.999)), 100)


# plot the results
#########################################################
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,5), ncols=2)

hist=ax1.hist(vals, bins=30,density=True, histtype='stepfilled', alpha=0.2)
pdf=ax1.plot(x, lndist.pdf(x), 'k-', lw=2, label="orig")
cdf=ax2.plot(xlg, lndist.cdf(xlg), 'k-', lw=2, label="orig")

pdf2=ax1.plot(x, lndist2.pdf(x), 'm-', lw=2, label="curve_fit on cfd")
pts=ax2.plot(vals, pvals, "bo")
cdf2=ax2.plot(xlg, lndist2.cdf(xlg), 'm-', lw=2, label="curve_fit on cfd")


ax1.grid(which="both")
ax1.legend()
ax1.set_title("pdf")
ax2.set_xscale("log")
ax2.grid(which="both")
ax2.set_title("cdf")
ax2.set_ylim((0,1))
ax2.legend()

fig.tight_layout()
fig.savefig("example.png", dpi=150)
```

[plot_from_the_code_above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rc1Sf.png)

Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: Try `vals = stats.lognorm.rvs(shape, size=1000000)` instead of `vals = stats.lognorm.rvs(shape, size=100)`, it will look better :-D

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I tried, it doesn't. Still the same trend...